# php/sql returns null even values present in db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am passing JSONObject as input into php script based on that the select query need to execute and fetch the values from database. But the values are not not fetching from database even the values are present in database.

```
<?php
$username = "xxx"; 
$password = "xxxx";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="xxxxx";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

//$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonString ='{"ilist":{"ib1":"6","ib2":"5"},"rlist":{},"generelist":{"genere1":"Adventure","genere2":"Animation","genere3":"Comedy","genere4":"Horror","genere5":"Fantasy","genere6":"Mystery"},"yearlist":{}}';
$obj = json_decode($jsonString,true);


$ib=array();
$rn=array();
$genere=array();
$year=array();

foreach ($obj['ilist'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
        $ib[$key] = $value;

    }
foreach ($obj['rlist'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
        $rn[$key] = $value;

    }

foreach ($obj['yearlist'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
        $year[$key] = $value;

    }

$val1=implode(',', $ib);
$val2=implode(',', $rn);
$val4=implode(',', $year);

array_walk($obj['generelist'],function(&$item1, $key){$item1="$item1=1";});
$stringgen = implode(' OR ', $obj['generelist']);

$myquery = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE 'it' IN ('$val1') OR `Re` IN ('$val2')  OR '". mysql_real_escape_string($stringgen)  ."'  OR `Year` IN ('$val4')";

$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}    


for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server); ?>
```

But it returns the null value even the values present in the database. Even when i open the php file in the IE from phpmyadmin it throws the null value. what is wrong with the script.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked the error log?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - no error but it returns null.

Comment: I should also note that using `echo mysql_error();` for anything but debugging purposes is also a security risk

Comment: Use backtick instead quotes in query `SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE 'it'`

Comment: yes changed. but it not working when values received from android $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');